# Can China decrypt SSL as soon as people using their ISP?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, firewalls, isp

While these VPNs can work inside of China, I wonder how private and secure they are since China is known for its great firewall, like most technically advanced countries. Are these methods working? Because China can "see through the traffic," so China keeps them alive?

https://www.reddit.com/r/cybersecurity/comments/121ftg6/can_china_decrypt_ssl_traffic/
claims China can decrypt SSL as soon as people use their ISP,
then methods for crossing the GFW seem to be some kind of honeypot for the Chinese government:

- Xray
- V2Ray
- Shadowsocks
- Iodine DNS tunnel
- pingtunnel ICMP tunnel
- SS over SSH over VLESS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any proper transport encryption (TLS, HTTPS, various VPN, ...) not only makes sure that the traffic is end-to-end encrypted and integrity protected with strong algorithms, but also that the other end is the intended party (authentication).

This prevents any party on the path to act as a man-in-the-middle - unless it is specifically trusted to do so by the client. But it does not prevent a MITM to do analysis on the encrypted traffic and on any potentially unencrypted meta data. It neither prevents a MITM blocking the traffic or parts of it or slowing it down.

The products you mention are not designed to trust the GFW as MITM. So the most which can be done by an MITM is to detect traffic as encrypted, block if it unwanted and then hope that this makes the client either stop attempting to communicate with the peer or do it in an unsafe way which then can be snooped more easily. See also [How the Great Firewall of China Detects and Blocks Fully Encrypted Traffic](https://gfw.report/publications/usenixsecurity23/en/).

Comment: but when use China ISP, do the users have to install their certificates first in order to use the network? @Steffen Ullrich

Comment: @Maxfield: I did not see in te reports of the researchers which are active one the topic, that users must install such certificates. So I assume that they don't need to.

Comment: but like most century ISP, users need to install the  certificates of the IPS first, in order to connect to network ?

Comment: @Maxfield: Users usually don't need to install a certificate to connect to an ISP.  Not sure what you are talking about, maybe you could provide some some information about this? They need of course to somehow authenticate to the ISP.

Comment: With your previous comments. and re-reading it again. better understanding now.